# Resizing A Range to Write a Range in its Place

Tags: excel, vba, resize, range, cell

I have a line of code where I am determining the size of a Range I stored, then writing the range to a different section of the worksheet. For some reason when I use `Range("MW6")` it works but if I use `Range(Cells(6,361))`  it does not work. Below is the line of code

```
Range(Cells(6,361)).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
```

I don't understand what the difference is because both MW6 and 6,361 reference the same cell? Error is a 1004.

Comment: Just for future reference, the reason you didn't get any responses is because of the way you tagged your question. For future, you probably should have tagged with [tag:excel] and [tag:vba] and/or [tag:excel-vba]. All your tags had less than 50 watchers (where [tag:excel] for example has 28.6k watchers).

Answer (score 1):

The reason you received the run-time error is because `Cell()` is a range object in itself.

You could have just used:

```
Cells(6,361).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value
```

or (as you've already expressed works):

```
Range("MW6").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value
```

And it's always a good idea to *qualify* your range objects with your worksheet and even your workbook.

```
Workbooks().Worksheets().Cells()
```

or, at the very least:

```
Worksheets().Cells()
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out for anyone interested. For some reason I had to put Range(Cells(6,361), Cells(6,361)). Would be interested to know if anyone knows why this is.